# Adding contacter's email to reply field in contact form email

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

In Drupal 7, when someone used our contact form, we would receive an email and could click "reply" in the email we received and have their email be in the "to" field. Since upgrading to Drupal 8, our own email shows up in the "to" field when replying to people who sent us an email through the contact box. Can anyone shed some light on how I can get the contacter's email to show up in the "to" field?

Can I set a "reply-to" field in the email to get this to work? I am using the core contact module, not webform but I am open to using the webform module if it can allow me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the Webform module. For a better explanation check out this: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/how-to-create-a-contact-form/